# How to get model summary from Spark ML Logistic Regression model?

Tags: apache-spark-ml

I am following an example from - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-classification-regression.html#multinomial-logistic-regression

When I try to get the model summary, I am facing an error. Here is my code with the error -

```
// START 

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression

// Load training data
val training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("file:///Users/my_username/Desktop/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt")

val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)

// Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)

// Print the coefficients and intercept for multinomial logistic regression
println(s"Coefficients: \n${lrModel.coefficientMatrix}")
println(s"Intercepts: \n${lrModel.interceptVector}")

val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
org.apache.spark.SparkException: No training summary available for this LogisticRegressionModel
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel$$anonfun$summary$1.apply(LogisticRegression.scala:1002)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel$$anonfun$summary$1.apply(LogisticRegression.scala:1002)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.summary(LogisticRegression.scala:1001)
  ... 48 elided
```

I want to print the metrics from the model after this step.

I have obtained the data from - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was using Spark version 2.2.0 and the document says to use 2.3.0

It works on 2.3.0